# What does "extern" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emacs, external, js2-mode

I just started to use `js2-mode` in Emacs, and I found some variables like `js2-global-externs` and `js2-additional-externs`.  The doc string says it is "A list of any extern names you'd like to consider always declared."

I don't understand what "extern" means here.  I only knew the "extern" keyword in C, so I started to discover what "extern" means.  I searched `JavaScript extern`/`Ecma-262 extern`/`web browser extern` but didn't get anything that looked promising.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extern` keyword has nothing to do with JavaScript. It's some configuration  on which **js2-mode** relies on to define the language.

For instance, I believe that you could add your own global variables `js2-global-externs` so that they get recognized.

Have a look at this file https://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/source/browse/trunk/js2-externs.el?r=57

Comment: Thanks.  Does "global variables" mean JavaScript variables or Emacs Lisp variables?